# How to send a message to any phone number with twilio?

Tags: twilio

When I send message to my phone numbers the message is sent successfully, but when I send the message to another phone number the message is not sent. How to send a message to any phone number?

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you using trial account? If so, you can only use numbers that you have verified in your account.